# Gap between collapsible sections on wix velo

Tags: mobile-website, velo

I’m currently building my studio website on wix. I’m using coded collapsible sections, I'm currently optimising for mobile and have this issue of the ‘let’s go’ having a big gap above it. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Images here
[image: expanded]
[image: closed]

This is the code

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    $w('#stepOneCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
        toggleBox($w('#stepOneCollabsibleStrip'), $w('#stepOneDownSign'),$w('#stepOneUpSign'));
    });
    $w('#stepTwoCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
        toggleBox($w('#stepTwoCollabsibleStrip'), $w('#stepTwoDownSign'),$w('#stepTwoUpSign'));
    });
    $w('#stepThreeCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
        toggleBox($w('#stepThreeCollabsibleStrip'), $w('#stepThreeDownSign'),$w('#stepThreeUpSign'));
    });
});

function toggleBox(boxElement, stepOneDownSign, stepOneUpSign) {
    const isCollapsed = boxElement.collapsed;
    if (isCollapsed) {
        stepOneDownSign.hide();
        stepOneUpSign.show();
        boxElement.expand();
    } else {
        stepOneUpSign.hide();
        stepOneDownSign.show();
        boxElement.collapse();
    }
}
```

Tried moving elements, have spent hours on google and cant find an answer